# Не удаляется папка в цикле (Linux)

Tags: linux, bash

Есть код, запускаю под root

```
#!/bin/bash
file="/var/www/site/data/www/site.ru/uploads/clean.lst"
/bin/mv -f $file $file.tmp
while IFS= read -r line
    do
        /bin/rm -r -f "$line" >> log.txt
    done <"$file.tmp"
/bin/mv -f $file.tmp $file
```

В файле lst есть строка

```
/var/www/site/data/www/site.ru/engine/cache/catalogue
```

Именно эту папку надо удалить.

Если просто в SSH вбиваю

```
/bin/rm -r -f "/var/www/site/data/www/site.ru/engine/cache/catalogue"
```

то папка удаляется.

Так в чем же дело?

Comment: @diproart, в этом выражении `$file` — переменная.

Comment: 1. Что вы хотели сказать вот этим `IFS=`? 2. При `-rf` ваш *log.txt* никак не пополнится. Всё делается гораздо проще: `rm -rf $(cat $file)` (если список не длинный и не содержит спецсимволов, в противном случае будет чуть посложнее).

Comment: если добавить в цикл проверку `[[ -d "$line" ]] && { echo "yes, exists: $line "; }`, то директория видна / то есть сам скрипт работает нормально?

Comment: @0andriy да, хотел подвести к проверке логики работы, но немного отвлекся)

Answer (score 1):

Не вижу никакого смысла использовать `IFS`, если вы хотите каким-то образом изменить, указать разделители (IFS -- Input Field Separator), то это нужно сделать по-другому, типа `IFS=$'\n'`, но в этом не смысла.

**Сейчас же получилось, что перезаписывается системная переменная IFS и всё идет не так, как вы ожидаете.**

Альтернативный вариант:

```
#!/bin/bash

# WORKDIR=/var/www/site/data/www/site.ru
# FILE="${WORKDIR}/uploads/clean.lst"
# cd $WORKDIR

for folder in $(cat /var/www/site/data/www/site.ru/uploads/clean.lst)
do
  echo "work on: $folder"
  # удалить: rm -rf $folder
  # проверить и удалить: [[ -d "$folder" ]] && { rm -rf "$folder"; }
done
```

> Использование команды `rm -rf`, тем более с привилегиями `root` несёт потенциальную угрозу всей системе, тем более в скриптах. Лучше так не делать, если нет прямой необходимости. Или проверять параметры перед их использованием. Простая ошибка в пути к файлам может стать фатальной для всей системы.

Answer (score 1):

И от меня свои пять копеек.

Из вопроса делаю выводы:

Имеется файл (file) с путями которые нужно рекурсивно удалить сохранив, что удалили в логфайл

Создаем тестовые каталоги:

```
~$ mkdir -vp test-{1..2}/inside-{1..2}/once-more{1..2}
mkdir: created directory 'test-1'
mkdir: created directory 'test-1/inside-1'
mkdir: created directory 'test-1/inside-1/once-more1'
mkdir: created directory 'test-1/inside-1/once-more2'
mkdir: created directory 'test-1/inside-2'
mkdir: created directory 'test-1/inside-2/once-more1'
mkdir: created directory 'test-1/inside-2/once-more2'
mkdir: created directory 'test-2'
mkdir: created directory 'test-2/inside-1'
mkdir: created directory 'test-2/inside-1/once-more1'
mkdir: created directory 'test-2/inside-1/once-more2'
mkdir: created directory 'test-2/inside-2'
mkdir: created directory 'test-2/inside-2/once-more1'
mkdir: created directory 'test-2/inside-2/once-more2'
```

Создаем clean.list:

```
~$ find . -type d -name "*more2" | tee clean.list
./test-1/inside-1/once-more2
./test-1/inside-2/once-more2
./test-2/inside-1/once-more2
./test-2/inside-2/once-more2
```

Создаем временный файл (зачем?):

```
~$ cp -vu clean.list{,.tmp}
'clean.list' -> 'clean.list.tmp'
```

Чистим пути избегая ошибки "слишком много аргументов" если напрямую скормить файл rm:

```
~$ xargs rm -rfv < clean.list | tee log.txt
removed directory './test-1/inside-1/once-more2'
removed directory './test-1/inside-2/once-more2'
removed directory './test-2/inside-1/once-more2'
removed directory './test-2/inside-2/once-more2'
```

Смотрим что в логе:

```
~$ cat log.txt
removed directory './test-1/inside-1/once-more2'
removed directory './test-1/inside-2/once-more2'
removed directory './test-2/inside-1/once-more2'
removed directory './test-2/inside-2/once-more2'
```

И что в итоге осталось:

```
~$ tree test-*
test-1
├── inside-1
│   └── once-more1
└── inside-2
    └── once-more1
test-2
├── inside-1
│   └── once-more1
└── inside-2
    └── once-more1
```

Теперь одним скриптом

```
!#/usr/bin/env bash

[ "$(id -u)" = "0" ] || { echo "Run as root. Exit."; exit 1; }

file="/var/www/site/data/www/site.ru/uploads/clean.lst"

cp -uv $file{,.tmp}

xargs rm -rfv < ${file}.tmp >> log.txt

# end of script
```